# Checking content of a drawing in HTML5

Tags: html, image, drawing

I'm trying to make a page that collects user drawn images and creates a composite image. The users are asked to draw a certain shape and I would like to avoid "vandalism" of the drawing which would effect the final composite.

Is there a way to check, in any language, that the image submitted is roughly comparable to the requested shape. I'd like to allow for a moderate level of deviation.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of the drawings and your budget, you could use Amazon's Mechanical Turk service to do the comparison, but that is likely overkill for the project.

Comment: I had no idea about Mechanical Turk, that's pretty cool stuff.
However, I'm only asking people to draw simple free hand circles, and would like to filer out things like people filling the entire canvas in.